# Python Caesar cipher decoding

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to Python and decided to make my own Caesar cipher encryptor. I've made the encrypter and it is ok, however, the decrypter can only successfully decrypt one word. If I enter a sentence, it merges the decryption all together. Is there an easy fix for this?

```
def decrypt():
    ciphertext = raw_input('Please enter your Encrypted sentence here:')
    shift = input('Please enter its shift value: ')
    space = []

    cipher_ords = [ord(x) for x in ciphertext]
    plaintext_ords = [o - shift for o in cipher_ords]
    plaintext_chars = [chr(i) for i in plaintext_ords]
    plaintext = ''.join(plaintext_chars)
    print 'Decryption Successful'
    print "" 
    print 'Your encrypted sentence is:', plaintext

decrypt()
```

Comment: Are you sure the problem does not start with your encryptor?

Comment: Your code looks ok here. Can you provide is with input and expected output?

Comment: Also you should never use `input` as that allows for arbitrary code execution. Instead do `int(raw_input())`.

Comment: no because it is a seperate file. I simply imput 'lipps xlivi' with a shift of '4' which should translate to 'hello there'. However, I get 'hellothere' with my current code.

Comment: I input 'lipps xlivi' with a shift of '4' which should return 'hello there' but instead, it returns 'hellothere' @TammoHeeren

Comment: @MatthewWillis Your encrypted text does not have the "space" character shifted. Either shift that as well as part of your encyrption, or have your decrypter not try to "un-shift" the space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I propose is to split your `raw_input()` at every space, iterate over each word in the split input, and then join the sentence back together with spaces. It seems to be the most canonical solution I could think of:

```
def decrypt():
    ciphertext = raw_input('Please enter your Encrypted sentence here:')
    shift = int(raw_input('Please enter its shift value: '))
    space = []

    # creat a list of encrypted words.
    ciphertext = ciphertext.split()

    # creat a list to hold decrypted words.
    sentence = []

    for word in ciphertext:
        cipher_ords = [ord(x) for x in word]
        plaintext_ords = [o - shift for o in cipher_ords]
        plaintext_chars = [chr(i) for i in plaintext_ords]
        plaintext = ''.join(plaintext_chars)
        sentence.append(plaintext)

    # join each word in the sentence list back together by a space.
    sentence = ' '.join(sentence)
    print 'Decryption Successful\n'
    print 'Your encrypted sentence is:', sentence

decrypt()
```

**Output:**

```
Please enter your Encrypted sentence here: lipps xlivi
Please enter its shift value:  4
Decryption Successful

Your encrypted sentence is: hello there
```

Notes:

- Never just do `input()` in Python 2.x because it uses `eval()` implicitly - which can be very dangerous. Use `int(raw_input())` instead.
- I removed the extra print statement you had to create a new line. Append a new line to your second print statement instead.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment about "hello there" as input, I suspect that the issue has to do with unprintable ascii characters. You are missing two crucial parts of your Caesar cypher.

For the first issue, consider:

```
>>> chr(ord(' ') - 4)
'\x1c'
```

Oh no! 4 characters to the left of the space (`32`) is the...ASCII file separator! How did Caesar fit *that* on a clay tablet?

For the second issue:

```
>>> chr(ord('A') - 4)
'='
```

The 'A' should wrap around in a true Caesar cypher, but instead you are exploring the hinterlands (well, not really) of non-alphabetic ASCII codes.

You thus need to include two important steps:

1. *Exclude* non-alphabetic characters from the Caesar cypher.
2. Make sure that letters wrap when approach the end: `A - 1` should equal `Z`.

Comment: so how do i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your probably wanted *not to decrypt* the `space` character as in your "encrypted" text it is *not encrypted*. If this is the case, here is the modified part of your code:

```
cipher_ords     = [ord(x)    if x != " " else -1  for x in ciphertext]
plaintext_ords  = [o - shift if o != -1  else -1  for o in cipher_ords]
plaintext_chars = [chr(i)    if i != -1  else " " for i in plaintext_ords]
```

(Let `cipher_ords` has `-1` for each space symbol and consequenlty in `plaintext_ords`, too. In `plaintext_chars` this `-1` will return back to the original `space` symbol.)